# Rewrite URL in .htaccess when 2 parameters are valid

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have some url like this:

```
index.php?cPath=23
index.php?cPath=23&sort=4a&language=En
index.php?currency=EUR&cPath=23&sort=4a&language=nl
index.php?currency=HUF&cPath=23&sort=4a&language=Hu
```

I want to redirect all of them to this link: `shop/food`. So I put this in my htaccess file:

```
# 301 --- /index.php?*cPath=23* => /shop/food
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cPath=23($|&)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /shop/food? [L,R=301]
```

This is working great.

But... I also have some URL's like this:

```
product_info.php?cPath=23&products_id=1324&language=En&osCsid=204giavieen8nmfv95b0dfrgs5
```

With the above code this link is also redirected to `/shop/food` because `cPath=23` is in the link.

I am looking now for a code which only redirect to `/shop/food` when index.php is in the link. In that way all these links will be redirected and the ones with `product_info.php?cPath=23` will get a 404 not found error.

Or another way, links with `product_info.php` or `products_id` in it will NOT be redirect.

Comment: the `product_info` should ideally not get directed to `shop/food` at all. Your rewrite rule specifies that it MUST match `^index\.php$` for the rewrite to occur.

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought too. But somehow that is not happening. Have to say this is in Joomla and there is one rule before: RewriteRule .* index.php [F] . But I think that has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cPath=23($|&)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /shop/food? [L,R=301]
```

Make sure this is placed right below `RewriteEngine On`.

**On the use of %{THE_REQUEST}:** `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`